# google share button only pulling in meta title

Tags: google-api, google-plus, share, facebook-opengraph

My google plus sharer button; unlike my facebook sharer right next to it. ***ONLY***, pulls in my     `<meta property="og:title" content="VERY COOL TITLE">` it completely ignores my open graph image and open graph description meta *(Facebook accepts it)*. Also, in fact it pulls in a random image from the page, not the open graph defined image at all!!

Within my head has all correct META (Facebook sharer sucks it all up)

Inline mark-up for google share.

```
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.verycoolwebsite.com/coolerthenyourwebsitebyfar/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/g_co.jpg" alt="Share on Google Plus"></a></li>
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Please include a link to the actual website as these issues are impossible to debug without seeing them in action.

Comment: Well I don't want to post a website to the public, search engines will grab it?

Comment: If it's accessible to the Google+/Facebook crawlers than it's already public and nothing is stopping search engines from indexing it.